# How to secure PHP website (not yet uploaded in the internet)

Tags: php, security

I have a PHP system inside a server which is not yet uploaded in the internet and can only be accessed using networking. (E.g. `192.168.1.190/php_system/index.php`) How can I fix the URL of this to avoid other computers to accessing files inside the `php_system` folder? And how can avoid them to accessing file using `CTRL + Left Click` or opening files inside `iframe` using another window?

Comment: 1) Configure permissions on your web server. 2) That is not a security issue, and you can't prevent it anyway.

Comment: Are you using apache?

Comment: Just don't share your files? On most systems files sharing can be turned off. Just do that. If you need Apache running, tell it to accept connections from 127.0.0.1 only. That allows you to debug but nobody else can see what you have... This can be set up per folder if needed, using the .htaccess file

Comment: Safe advise, try php frameworks. It works great in terms of security. regarding file sharing, are you using Linux Distro or MS Server?

Comment: Yes I'm using apache. How can I configure permission? I mean, if they can access it using `192.168.1.190/php_system/index.php`, and change `index.php` to `addclient.php` for example, then they can access it.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow, MS Server.

Comment: @Floris, how can I do that? I'm actually a newbie with regards to configuring stuffs.

Comment: Really, if your main security component is that nobody can guess the URL of the scripts, then you failed. Accessing a script that the user has no right to do should be prevented inside the script!

Comment: @Floris, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Comment: I'm wondering, if you want to prevent most of the users from viewing your site, you may just create accounts(with passwords) for each user that is allowed and make a login form at the index, otherwise the client won't be able to view your website. If there are few users, you may even just use a .htaccess and configure some passwords ...

Comment: @Sven, that is why I'm asking how because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You probably want to read about session authentication and how to do a login in PHP. Securing the server so that nobody can see it is useless once you want to go online.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV, I have. The problem is, they can know the filename if they use `CTRL + left click` on a link. And they can just rename the URL to access that file directly without going through the username and password.

Comment: It's *impossible* to completely prevent `CTRL + left click`

Comment: Ow. By the title of the question, i was misguided that you need some beta tester. Tell your goal here. Just do not tell your ip to whom you trust. If you mean you have created a web application then try a login system.

Comment: @xjshiya the answer of Tigger below is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your Apache Virtual host to allow access only from certain IPs. Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName EDIT.THIS.com
    ServerAlias EDIT.THIS.IF.YOU.HAVE.ONE.com
    DocumentRoot "/full/path/to/root"
    <Directory /full/path/to/root>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from 192.168.0.1 EDIT.TO.ANOTHER.IP AND.ANOTHER
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, add a "auth" value (that will require a login and password) like this:

```
<Directory /full/path/to/root>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Admin"
        // NOTE: do not include this in your website folder
        AuthUserFile /path/to/.passwd_file 
        Require user user1 user2
</Directory>
```

Edit: Corrected the `Order` values.

Comment: This configuration is wrong! The last keyword in the `Order` directive is also the default for anything not mentioned. So `Order Deny,Allow` allows access per default, unless it is denied. There is no denial, this config is useless. Correct usage would be `Order Allow,Deny`.

Comment: Thanks Sven - you are correct and the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/platform/windows.html. this will show you directives on how to configure your Apache server on windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory you want to protect, add a file called `.htaccess` (the period matters)

In this file, put the following three lines (EDITED based on Sven's inputs)

```
order deny,allow
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all
```

Now it should be impossible for anyone but you (logged in on the machine where Apache is running) from seeing the contents. Any file sharing that is active has to be turned off separately. Alternatively, you add a line that includes the IP address of the machine from which you want to access the server instead of `127.0.0.1` - you can even have multiple lines of allowed addresses, include ranges, ...

You will find a ton more information at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order

Comment: This is wrong. `Order Allow,Deny` denies by default, unless there is an allow exception, which additionally can be excepted with a deny again. Correct would be `Order Deny,Allow`.

Comment: @sven - your comment on the other answer contradicts what you say here. In one case you say "allow,deny" is wrong; in the other you say "deny, allow" is wrong... Can you please elaborate?  I took this example directly from the documentation. Pretty sure it works.

Comment: No contradiction. Your example has both Allow and Deny directives, while the other answer has not. This difference is important. And your "documentation" has an error. Just look at the first user comment on http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/ - and then please stop using secondary sources when the primary source of documentation is as easily available: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order It is correctly explained there...

Comment: Thanks for correcting me and explaining. Foolish me thought a site like "htaccess-guide.com" might be authoritative. I figured if their domain name was devoted to just one topic they might know what they were talking about. I see the difference now; so changing the order of directives to "deny all" first, and "allow xx.xx.xx.xx" second would address the problem you identified explicitly and leave no doubt about what was and wasn't allowed, right?

Comment: No. The order of the directives `Allow` and `Deny` in the file does not matter. `Order Allow,Deny` first evaluates any Allow if access should be granted. If the answer is yes, all Deny are evaluated to check if access should be denied. If you state "Deny from all", this always matches - no access possible. With `Order Deny,Allow`, first the "Deny from all" denies access, but then the Allow grants access.

Comment: @sven, having read the original documentation I see I still had it wrong, but I believe now it has been fixed. The order of the lines doesn't matter - the `order allow,deny` directive instructs Apache to first look at ALL `allow` statements, then overrides them with ALL `deny` statements. So the original answer locked out everyone with the `deny from all` statement. It should now be fixed though.